# Select File from file manager via Intent

Tags: android, file, android-intent

**What I wanna do:**

I wanna get the path as a String of a file, which I choose via an Android File Manager.

**What I have:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with ..."), FILE_SELECT_CODE);
```

This code, works nearly fine for me, but there is one problem. I can only select my file with the following apps:

[image]

**My Question:**

Does anyone have a working code for choosing any file via the Android File Manager?

Comment: "but there is one problem: I can only select my file with the following apps" -- why is that a problem? "Does anyone have a working code for choosing any file via the Android File Manager?" -- Android does not *have* a file manager. The closest thing is [the Storage Access Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html), available on API Level 19+.

Comment: Its a problem, 'cause I also wanna send .pdf or something like this, so I need to pic my file with a File Manager, not with the Gallery

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*"); 
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

For samsung devices to open file manager use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
```

For more reference checkout http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Comment: have you added intent.setType("*/*"); ?

Comment: have you given write & read external storage permissions in your manifest, if problem still exists please post your logcat

Comment: oh shit I'm sry, now it doesn't crash, but there is still no possibility to choose a file via my file manager, I'm using usually

Comment: what is the problem now?

Comment: I wanna choose my file not with the galery or something like that, but with my file explorer, cause i also wanna choose pdf and so on ... but I cannot choose my file explorer in the Intent. Look here: http://i.imgur.com/yFW6weD.png

Comment: try setting intent.setType("file/*");

Comment: With intent.setType("file/*"); only 3 apps appear ://

Comment: which device are you using?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Neo

Answer (score 2):

So for my Samsung device this worked:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_SELECT_CODE);
```