# Pick any file using intent in android

Tags: android, intentfilter, filepicker

I'm using following method to call pick any file but it doesn't work properly.

```
private void fileIntent(int file)
    {
        if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ICShowFileCabinetDetails.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, file);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), file);
        }

    }
```

Following permissions are set in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

OnActivtyresult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE && data != null) {
            try {
                mProPic = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

//                String filename = selectedImage.getLastPathSegment();

                String[] filenames = picturePath.split("\\/");


                int count = filenames.length;
                String name = filenames[count - 1];


                imagepickerselected = 1;
                UploadIamgeinServer(1, name);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Choose file getting open whenever i click to choose file in button click. But all files are shown like hidden except images, Click doest work.[image]  Without method in it button click works fine.  If anyone found errors in code please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: can you update your log and what is your android version.. you are giving intent in `else`

Comment: Please post the logs?

Comment: Sorry friends question updated .  App isn't crashing. Please refer pic attachment.

Comment: follow my answer you can use your file extension instead of xls

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya it works only for excel files right? My requirement is to choose any file.

Comment: no it work for any i just check the extension of file

Comment: let's  see my update answer i remove that confuse line

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya : it shows the same... I've attached a screenshot here , looks like hidden files in chooser

Comment: click on 3 dot overflow botton and click show sd card option

Answer (score 0):

try this code this my code only for .xls use yours.
or add read and write permission in manifest file

oncreate declare permission

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},23
            );
        }
    }
```

onclick of you button write this code

```
path= String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                File file = new File(path);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.ms-excel");

                try {
                    startActivityForResult(pdfOpenintent.createChooser(intent, "Select file"), 0);                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                }
```

onactivityresult yud get file path

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if (requestCode == 0) {
                Uri data = result.getData();

                else{
                    //  CommonMethods.ShowMessageBox(CraneTrackActivity.this, "Invalid file type");
                    Toast.makeText(Import_act.this,"Wrong File Selected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add like this intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
. For more visit this link, [Select File from file manager via Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854575/select-file-from-file-manager-via-intent). I hope this may help you.